# URL Routing in MVC 3

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, url, url-routing

my current url is something like this => http://localhost:4330/Restaurants/?Location=Manchester&Cuisine=0&NetProfit=0&Turnover=0&MaxPrice=120000&SortPriceBy=Low&Page=0

i want it to make something like this => http://localhost:4330/Restaurants/Manchester/?Cuisine=Chinese&MaxPrice=120000

Where Param Query string that doesnt have values (0) will not be included on query string URL
Is it possible?

Comment: if you want to hide certain parameter from showing as querystring then you can just pass them via other methods, i.e. form values.

Answer (score 5):

**UPDATED**

stringAdd this to Global.asax routes

```
            routes.MapRoute(
                "Name of route", // Route name
                "Restaurants/{cityid}/", // URL with parameters
                new { controller = "Restaurants", action = "Index" } // Parameter defaults
            );
```

This is controller:

```
public ActionResult Index(string city, int cuisine = 0, int ChineseMaxPrice=0)
{
  Return View();
}
```

Like int cuisine = 0 - this set the default value to parameter if this parameter is not set in querystring

string city - is a parameter that should be in string (not optional)

Comment: Isn't that route a double wildcard? it matches any controller that has any action..? Or is the `new` clause where you are specifying the specific controller and action?

Comment: sorry, i made a small mistake/ updated. This is additional route

Answer (score 1):

Try adding add the corresponding route:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "Restaurants",
    "Restaurants/{city}",
    new { controller = "Restaurants", action = "Index", city = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

which would map to the `Index` action on the `Restaurants` controller:

```
public ActionResult Index(string city) 
{
    ...
}
```